# How do i swap values?

Tags: php, sorting, yii, swap

I have list of departments, against each department there is a button which is UP and another button DOWN

When you click on UP Button, It calls the function up..

```
Public function actionUP($id, $sort_order){

    $allDeps = Department::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $depArr = array();
    foreach ($allDeps as $department){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['id'] = $department->id;
        $temp['sort_order'] = $department->sort_order;
        $depArr[] = $temp;
    }
```

Now if i var dump this array `depArr` i am getting an array..

```
array (size=17)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '142' (length=3)
      'sort_order' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '141' (length=3)
      'sort_order' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '144' (length=3)
      'sort_order' => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '140' (length=3)
      'sort_order' => string '6' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '139' (length=3)
      'sort_order' => string '3' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '143' (length=3)
      'sort_order' => string '4' (length=1)
```

I have list of departments, position is actually `sort_order` and there are up and down button against department, up buttons calls for `actionUP` which sends the `up?id=143&sort_order=4`

If a user clicks on up button against position 4 its position should changed to 3, and the department at 3 should go to 4 and ALSO UPDATE INTO DATABASE..

I am using Yii 1.1 PHP framework

[image]

Comment: So what is the exact question?

Comment: First thing is how do i swap values, `'sort_order' => string '4'` to swap with `'sort_order' => string '3'` in the array..

Answer (score 0):

***Flow:***

1. Search using

> array_search('whateverID', array_column($depArr, 'id'));

2. Now you have the index and the sort order, you just need to search for sort order - 1 now.

> array_search($depArr[x]['sort_order']-1, array_column($depArr,
>   'sort_order'));

3. You now have both element's index, swap the sort order or unset and set again. Hope this helps.